# why does the Eigen vectors calulated from accelerate framework differ in sign?

Tags: ios, eigenvector, accelerate-framework

Hi for the following 9x9 input matrix

```
6.522752 0.985874 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -1.239167 1.833633 1.542076 
0.985874 5.591528 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.833633 6.220998 -3.414516 
0.000000 0.000000 4.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.542076 -3.414516 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 6.522752 0.985874 0.000000 -3.478164 -2.197849 -2.923418 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.985874 5.591528 0.000000 -2.197849 5.979956 -5.347403 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 4.000000 -2.923418 -5.347403 0.000000 
-1.239167 1.833633 1.542076 -3.478164 -2.197849 -2.923418 7.943390 4.655086 2.544306 
1.833633 6.220998 -3.414516 -2.197849 5.979956 -5.347403 4.655086 26.187047 -8.514617 
1.542076 -3.414516 0.000000 -2.923418 -5.347403 0.000000 2.544306 -8.514617 10.540343
```

Eigen vectors from dsyevd_ (lapack) are

```
-0.240839 -0.138424 0.519974 0.115826 -0.370674 0.288584 -0.393926 0.431228 0.277905 
0.244180 -0.537519 -0.093966 0.107875 -0.362227 0.419277 0.386924 0.074391 -0.410777 
-0.085046 0.080591 -0.087321 0.405798 0.480233 0.520947 0.351553 0.085795 0.425460 
0.326714 -0.343211 0.687494 -0.137128 0.486896 -0.164580 0.125151 -0.051854 -0.038804 
-0.025542 0.219686 0.021264 -0.732741 0.149150 0.596999 -0.112391 -0.057387 -0.138370 
0.347073 0.682316 0.396621 0.256967 -0.282724 0.116437 0.200305 -0.155640 -0.181131 
0.802559 -0.030022 -0.272760 -0.009368 -0.014541 0.068134 -0.376412 0.154091 0.332006 
0.041949 0.027988 0.028721 -0.432580 -0.332588 -0.207674 0.588240 0.161115 0.532709 
-0.037747 -0.228302 0.086833 0.036285 -0.225159 0.157222 -0.124072 -0.849258 0.354327
```

Eigen vectors from opencv

```
0.037747 0.228302 -0.086833 -0.036285 0.225159 -0.157222 0.124072 0.849258 -0.354327 
0.041949 0.027988 0.028721 -0.432580 -0.332588 -0.207674 0.588240 0.161115 0.532709 
0.802559 -0.030022 -0.272760 -0.009368 -0.014541 0.068134 -0.376412 0.154091 0.332006 
0.347073 0.682316 0.396621 0.256967 -0.282724 0.116437 0.200305 -0.155640 -0.181131 
0.025542 -0.219686 -0.021264 0.732741 -0.149150 -0.596999 0.112391 0.057387 0.138370 
0.326714 -0.343211 0.687494 -0.137128 0.486896 -0.164580 0.125151 -0.051854 -0.038804 
-0.085046 0.080591 -0.087321 0.405798 0.480233 0.520947 0.351553 0.085795 0.425460 
-0.244180 0.537519 0.093966 -0.107875 0.362227 -0.419277 -0.386924 -0.074391 0.410777 
-0.240839 -0.138424 0.519974 0.115826 -0.370674 0.288584 -0.393926 0.431228 0.277905
```

The values differ in position and also in sign. how can i fix this issue in lapack.

Answer (score 2):

Eigen vectors are unique up to a real scaling factor. That means that if x is an eigen vector, then `l.x` (where l is a scalar) is one, too. In particular, if `x` is an eigenvector or `M` then `-x` is one, too. Note that very often eigen vectors are unit-normalised such that `||x|| = 1`, but of course that still leaves you with two possible vectors (`x` and `-x`). You can resolve this ambiguity by taking the eigenvector `j.x` where `j` is the sign of the first non-negative coordinate of `x`.

EDIT The eigenvectors can also be returned in different orders. Usually, they are returned in decreasing order of the corresponding eigenvalue.

In your example, the eigenvectors seem to be related to different eigenvalues, can you confirm that?

Comment: can you please tell me the j(first non-negative coordinate) value with respect to the above example.

Comment: @pradeepa: Régis B. means that, for each eigenvector, find the first non-zero (not non-negative) coordinate in it. If it is negative, then negate the eigenvector. Thus [1, 2, 3] stays [1, 2, 3]; [0, 1, 2] stays [0, 1, 2]; [-1, 2, 3] becomes [1, -2, -3]; and [0, -1, 2] becomes [0, 1, -2].

Comment: The LAPACK eigenvalue routines (dsyev, etc) return the eigenvalues in ascending order, which results in the difference you see here.